# LAN Huge File Transfer

Tags: windows, arch-linux

How to send a Huge file more than 8GB to Several clients on a Local Area Network., At the same time., like File Multicast.., 
.
No Intermediate software.,
No Permission Required at Client or Receiver

Comment: You might want to refine your question a bit. For example: is the sending end a GNU/Linux computer or a Windows computer? Are all clients Windows computers? What have you tried this far? Describe as clearly as possible what you're trying to accomplish. See also [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If in doubt, use Bittorrent. :)

Comment: What do you mean by "no intermediate software"?  If you want multicast file transfer on Windows or Linux, you are going to need server and client software.

Comment: try http://filemulticaster.sourceforge.net/ see is that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [UDPcast](https://www.udpcast.linux.lu/exe.html).

> UDPcast is a file transfer tool that can send data simultaneously to many destinations on a LAN. This can for instance be used to install entire classrooms of PC's at once. The advantage of UDPcast over using other methods (nfs, ftp, whatever) is that UDPcast uses UDP's multicast abilities: it won't take longer to install 15 machines than it would to install just 2.
>   **<sub>From https://www.udpcast.linux.lu/index.html</sub>**

It's an old software program (2006), but it still worked fine for me.

I've never set it up in a perfect way, so 1 or 2 transmissions usually failed, but it saved time during my classes sending a large ISO file to my students at once.

> ### Basic usage
>
> ```
> udp-sender -f outfile
> ```
>
>
>   Starts the sender program. The program waits for
>   connections from the receivers. As soon as a key is pressed on either
>   one of the receivers or on one of the senders, the data transfer will
>   start.
>
> ```
> udp-receiver -f outfile
> ```
>
>
>   Starts the receiver program. It automatically
>   locates (via broadcast) any sender on the local net, and connects to
>   it.
>   **<sub>From https://www.udpcast.linux.lu/cmdlinedoc.html</sub>**

Comment: We’re looking for substantial answers that provide some explanation and context.  Generally, an answer should explain how to solve the problem rather than just mentioning a tool; please explain why you’re recommending it as a solution, and see [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5329/354511)